# How can I deploy to Google Compute Engine via CI/CD

Tags: docker, jar, continuous-integration, google-compute-engine, continuous-deployment

I have a jar and a docker image that I wish to deploy to my Compute Engine instance and run docker compose down/up after it being there. I can use git on the instance if that helps.

I want to do this using CI/CD tools, something like Google cloud build, gitlab, bitbucket pipelines. Ideally something that has a free tier.

I am aware this might be a bit vague, so am willing to add more details if necessary

Answer (score 1):

In your case you can try [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/) and use an [ssh plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/SSH+plugin) to execute commands on your remote instance and send the files. There are some considerations that you might want to take before doing that.

1.- Add your ssh keys in the metadata for that [instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys) .

2.- Make sure your [firewall rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls) allow incoming traffic on port 22.

Once your instance allows incoming traffic on port 22 and you’d installed the ssh plugin, you just have to type the commands (docker-compose up/down) in the ssh section added by the plugin.